# Comparing two LINQ queries, where statement Hasvalue vs !=null

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, datacontext

I have this function has two requirements

1. return only orders that have an `OrderDate` value other than null
2. return orders that were placed in the year specified in the parameter year or later

Which `WHERE` statement meets the requirements? And why?

```
static IQueryable<Order> lookUp (int year)
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext  d = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var orders = from order in d.Orders
 This line ==>      where order.OrderDate.HasValue && order.OrderDate.Value.Year >=year
        OR ==>      where order.OrderDate.Value!=null && order.OrderDate.Value.Year >=year
                    select order;
        return orders.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that the second line has `order.OrderDate.Value!=null` or should have that read `order.OrderDate!=null`?

Answer (score 4):

[`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) will tell you whether it is null or not. [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) will get the non-null value, or throw an exception if it's null. Since you do not want to throw in the case of a null value, you shouldn't use the second.

Using `!= null` (on the nullable itself, not on the `.Value` of it) is equivalent to using `HasValue` (the compiler generates a `HasValue` call). The following are both valid, then, and which to use is a stylistic choice.

```
where order.OrderDate.HasValue && ...
where order.OrderDate != null && ...
```